# Android - Activity Hierarchy (back button)

Tags: android, android-intent, back-button

I have the following model:

- `MainActivity` navigates (through a button) to `ActivityA`.
- `ActivityA` displays list of records as a `ListView` (from `SQLite` database).
- If I click on any record, an intent will start `ActivityB` which displays the data of the selected record to be edited.
- If I press on the device back button it will take me back to `ActivityA`.
- `ActivityB` has a 'save' button, which if clicked will open new intent of `ActivityA` with the updated records (after edit), also, this button will `finish()` `ActivityB`.
- Here if I press the device back button (after saving `ActivityB` and opening `ActivityA`), it will take me to the old `ActivityA` with the data before update (the older version of `ActivityA`), then on the second click on device back button, it will go back to `MainActivity`.

The question is: How can I let the device back button always go back to the hierarchical parent, instead of going to previous open activities?

OR

How can I kill the old instance of `ActivityA` if the user clicks on the save button in `ActivityB`?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag in the `Intent` used to launch `ActivityA`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
startActivity(intent);
```

If `ActivityA` being launched is already running in the current task, then all of the other activities on top of it will be closed including `ActivityA` and `ActivityA` is restarted with the new Intent. There will be no need to call `finish()` on `ActivityB` explicitly.

Comment: All of the answers are great! I like this one. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In `ActivityB`, after the save, you should call `finish()` instead of opening a new instance of `ActivityA`. You should have `ActivityA` re-query and update the `ListView`.

Comment: I have made `ActivityA` requery when calling `onResume()`, do you recommend this?

Comment: That's one possibility. It's preferred if you have a way to know that something has changed. This is usually done automatically with a `CursorLoader`, but that requires you to be querying a `ContentProvider`. Another option is that when you launch `ActivityB`, use `startActivityForResult()`. In `ActivityB`, after you save but before you call `finish`, you can call `setResult(RESULT_OK, null);` In ActivityA again, override `onActivityResult()` and if the result is `RESULT_OK` then you can requery.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `finish()` in `OnPause()` of ActivityA and
add this method to ActivityB.

```
@Overrride
  public void onBackPressed(View v) {

    Intent MainActivityIntent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.Class); 
    startActivity(MainActivityIntent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

just try this, it really works...